# BeagleBone Black User Leds

Tags: uart, beaglebone-black

Is it possible to set some of four available user leds to show serial port activity, like we can set it to show mmc activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ubuntu linux on BBB, but other Linux will work similarly.

The user LED mode can be accessed using the following command:

```
echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:green\:usr3/trigger > /dev/null
```

Where `none` can be replaced with one of the following:

```
none nand-disk mmc0 mmc1 timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu0 default-on transient
```

I am unaware of any option to "connect" a user LED to a serial port. The only option I see is "manually" writing 0 or 1 to one of the brightness files upon receiving data in your program.

Optionally work around running as root by issuing a `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:green\:usr3/brightness` once.

In Perl you can blink the LED as follows:

```
my $ledState = 0;
while( 1 ) {
  $ledState ^= 1;   # toggle state
  open( LED , ">" , "/sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:green\:usr3/brightness" ) or die "Cannot open file for LED control: $!\n";;
  print LED $ledState;
  close( LED );
  sleep( 1 );
}
```